# incorrect c++ output when executing

Tags: c++

I am trying to replicate the following program but without including the cout function, this is the program with the cout function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  bool incorrect = 1;
  int temp;
  int i = 0;
  int peopleInGroup = 1;
  string x = "";
  int max;
  stringstream ss;
  cout << "Input the number of people in a group: 2 to  ";
  getline (cin, x);
  ss << x;
  ss >> max;
  while(incorrect == 1)
  {
      i++;
      cout << "Testing: " << i << endl;
      peopleInGroup = 1;
      while(peopleInGroup < max)
      {
          peopleInGroup++;
          cout << "Remainder of (" << i << " /" << peopleInGroup << ") =" << (i % peopleInGroup) << "     =" << (peopleInGroup - 1) << "     ";
          if((i % peopleInGroup) == (peopleInGroup - 1))
          {
              cout << "TRUE" << endl;
              if(peopleInGroup == max)
              {
                  incorrect = 0;
          break;
              }
              else{}
          }
          else
          {
              cout << "FALSE" << endl;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  if(incorrect == 0)
  {
      cout << endl << "The answer is " << i;
  }
  else
  {
      cout << endl << "Unable to find the answer";
  }
  cin >> temp;
}
```

which when run shows

```
Input the number of people in a group: 2 to
```

and when I type 3, it comes out with 5 which is correct:

```
Input the number of people in a group: 2 to 3
...
The answer is 5
```

without cout, however when I do this the program comes out with an incorrect answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  bool incorrect = 1;
  int temp;
  int i = 0;
  int peopleInGroup = 1;
  string x = "";
  int max;
  stringstream ss;
  cout << "Input the number of people in a group: 2 to  ";
  getline (cin, x);
  ss << x;
  ss >> max;
  while(incorrect == 1)
  {
      i++;
      peopleInGroup = 1;
      while(peopleInGroup < max)
      {
          peopleInGroup++;
          if((i % peopleInGroup) == (peopleInGroup - 1))
          {
          if(peopleInGroup == max)
          {
            incorrect = 0;
          }
          }
      }
  }
  if(incorrect == 0)
  {
      cout << endl << "The answer is " << i;
  }
  else
  {
      cout << endl << "Unable to find the answer";
  }
  cin >> temp;
}
```

which is always

```
max - 1
```

for example, if I put in 3, it comes out with 2

Comment: Did you notice that there is a `break;` missing in second variant (twice)?

Comment: Side note: It's better style to use literals `true`/`false` for boolean values; but if so, don't check `if(condition == true/false)`, do `if(condition/!condition)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss the break statement in the following code.

cout is not necessary but the break statement is to come out from the execution block. If you put the break statement as given in above code you will get the desired output